# Replicating a Crystal Report created by an ERP and sending it from server to client

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, crystal-reports

The company I work for has an ERP that generates Crystal Reports using data from the ERP Database (MS SQL Server).

Example: Mitch from sales (who we've purchased a very expensive ERP license for) wants to know how many hammers we have in stock. He goes into the ERP clicks the "Report" button, and a new window pops up with a crystal report showing him how many hammers are in stock.

My boss would like Jeremy (who does not have a very expensive ERP license) to be able to see these reports as well. Jeremy needs to be able to right click an item (e.g. hammer) in our document management software and generate a report from there.

I have spent more hours trying to figure out how to do this than I'd like to admit. I am successfully sending back a string of all the right info based on the selected item, but can't figure out how to get it sent back as a Crystal Report (which is absolutely necessary for some reason which has yet to be explained to me). The report can be in any file format (i.e. ttx, rpt, html) as long as its laid out just like the report generated by the ERP.

Additional info:

- I can make Crystal Reports just fine in the Crystal Reports for Visual Studio SDK but can't successfully use an existing report as a template
- I have access to everything on the server
- My server side code is ASP.NET using C#
- The reports are generated from stand-alone rpt files, rpt + vbscript files, and rpt + sql + ttx files
- The report I'm currently trying to replicate uses a ttx and sql file to populate the data
- The string I'm sending back is obtained using an altered version of the sql query that I've made into a stored procedure

I'm probably missing some crucial info that is needed to answer this question so feel free to ridicule me and ask for whatever you want. That's what my boss does.

thanks @BoldAsLove. In answer to your questions... 1) The goal is to generate the reports server side and send them back to the client (I'm thinking as a pdf or html). I'm trying to get it working on the client first and then transfer it over to the server because our server is running on Windows 7 and I can't figure out how to remote debug a program on that OS. 2) I've tried spinning up a report on my client application several different ways with different results (feel free to ask additional clarifying questions on this. I've been in and out of this project for the last couple of months and my brain is fragmented to the point where I might be saying something stupid or wrong).  I can successfully get a report with the right data if I build it from scratch in Visual Studio and set the Data Source in Crystal Database Expert as a DataSet that I make within the project (with column names that match the ones in the ERP database). If I try to generate the report based off of an existing report I either get an error saying

> Error in File CrystalReport1
>   Report GUID
>   Error in formula Object_Visibility:
>   formula =  (Trim ({Hammer_Report_ttx.HammerID}) = '') 
>   This Field is not known
>   Details: errorKind

or a login window pops up and I fail to login (and I've used every login credential combo on our server that I can think of).

Comment: I used to work a TON with both client and server side report generations using Crystal Reports (which is a BEAST, i think the documentation is somewhere over 3000 pages!). I will do my best to help, but its been a while. 1) are you generating the reports client or server side? 2) are you getting any errors during generation, and if so what are they (for either client or serverside generation I'd like to see them). I can help more after these are answered.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @BoldAsLove. I edited my original post attempting to answer your questions.

Comment: Start by doing some stare and compares between the working and non-working version. Focus on the datasource. If you can't see anything obviously different try doing a findall for that field in both documents, see if anything is missing in the non-working version.